# Link that opens a NEW page and runs javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I would like to know how to open a page, and then on that page, run javascript (that is set by the link on the first page). I have tried this:
`<a href = "http://www.example.com/otherpage" onclick = "javascript_on_otherpage()">LINK DISPLAY NAME HERE</a>`
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You generally can't do that, when you can it's called XSS.

Comment: Is the new page a page who's code you control?

Comment: @JBWar - since it looks like you're new here, this place does not work like a forum where you post a question and come back the next day.  You should check back here several times in the first 30 minutes after posting because if your question is not clear to everyone and people have asked clarifying questions, you must be able to clear things up or your question will get downvoted or closed because it is not clear.  If you are busy, then don't post your question until you can check back several times within the first 30 minutes.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, I didn't know about that.

Comment: @vihan1086 No, it does not use PHP. it just uses html, javascript, and css.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, the page is one that i control the code.

Comment: @JBWar I've added my answer, it uses complete JavaScript. It'll allow you to run whatever Javascript you want on the target page

Comment: Dont know what the issue with the question is.  Clear enough to me.  And obviously you control the new page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the new page is a page whose code you control, then you can pass a query parameter to the new page via the link and you can have the javascript in the new page check for that query parameter and, if found, run some code in the page upon page load.

```
<a href = "http://www.example.com/otherpage?runOnStartup=3">LINK DISPLAY NAME HERE</a>
```

And the startup javascript in the new page would check for the `runOnStartup` query parameter and run some code based on its value.

---

If the new page is in the same origin as your current page, then you could open the new page in a new window and then after it opened, you could call a function in that new window.  But, your previous page would have to still be running in order to do that.

---

If the new page is in a different origin and you do not control the code in that new page, then you cannot do what you're asking for browser security reasons.

Comment: Coming back to this old question of mine as a much more experienced JavaScript developer, I'm changing this to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, no problem.

Note that IE has weird incompatibilities in this area of the DOM.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <a id="foo" href>Click me!</a>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('foo').onclick = onFooClick;

    function onFooClick(e) {
      var scriptToInject, popUp, node, importedNode;

      scriptToInject = 'document.body.innerHTML = "Hello from the injected script!";';
      popUp = window.open('about:blank');
      node = document.createElement('script');
      node.textContent = scriptToInject;
      importedNode = popUp.document.importNode(node, true);
      popUp.document.body.appendChild(importedNode);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on a Mac.

Answer (score -2):

> **Warning:** Do *not* use the following code in any remotely-production related machine. It is trivially susceptible to XSS and allows anybody to run any JS code on your website. This means that a malicious website could trivially steal your users' identities and other sensitive data. I highly recommend I recommend against using the method described in this answer in any form/

---

### Page 1

```
<a href="mypage.html?javascript=URL_ENCODED_JAVASCRIPT_HERE"></a>
```

### Page 2

```
<script>
    var javascript = <?=$_GET['javascript'] ?>;
    eval(decodeURIComponent(javascript));
</script>
```

If you don't have PHP, use:

```
var javascript = window.location.href.match(/[^?=]+$/)[0];
```

*I haven't tested this code so it may need some fixing. I am also assuming you own both pages. If the target page isn't yours, you can't run JavaScript on it for security reasons.

to URL encode your JavaScript, go [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), type your JavaScript, and hit encode.

Comment: That did not work for me. It just goes to the second page with nothing special. I included your page 2 script, and i made sure that the javascript is not defined in a separate file (in case that makes a difference).

Comment: yes. i did encode it. from function(); to function()%3B

Comment: @JBWar is function defined on Page 2?

Comment: @JBWar put the code for Page 2 in a window.onload={} if function is defined on page 2

Comment: @JBWar try passing in an alert()

Comment: i am going to try in a blank new html file. What did you mean when you said that you cant run javascript on someone's website for security reasons? Just asking... does that mean that you can control only files within your domain name? will it work on local files?

Comment: @JBWar You can do it on local files, or any file you can change the code on. The reason you can't run JavaScript on other people's sites is because you could have a key logger logging peoples passwords and personal details, that is the one example

Comment: when i do an alert, it works, but when i do a function, it doesn't

Comment: @JBWar That's because the function is not defined on both pages. Put the function's code before `var javascript`.

Comment: ok, that worked. but the function is still acting weird. As a test, i made the function result in an alert. It worked. When i put `document.getElementById('hide').style.display='block';` in it, it does not work, or even show the alert.

Comment: @JBWar and is *everything* in a `window.onload`?

Comment: no, not yet. i forgot to do that on the new file. All of it should be in the same script, or no?

Comment: @JBWar yes, they should. If you need, put your code in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and I can help you debug it

Comment: I am not very familiar with window.onload . What is the syntax?

Comment: @JBWar http://pastebin.com/ws8SzVW2 also, learn about `window.onload` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Comment: Thanks! Just to let you know, the window.onload is not needed. you just need to put the code at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The warning in the answer says "do not use in production". Actually I'd say "do not use AT ALL!". If you control both sites, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/29460207/2448440 - and it is even easier to use, because you don't have to URL encode your script!